# Better way to select all columns from first table and only one column from second table on inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

### Graphical Explaination

Table 1's columns:

```
|a|b|c|d|e|
```

Table 2's columns:

```
|a|x|y|z|
```

I want only a, b, c, d, e, x.  I only want column 'a' from table 1, not column 'a' from table 2.

### Wordy Explaination

I have two tables with one column sharing a common name.  If I use a Select * and use an inner join, I get all the columns returned including two columns with the same name.

I want to select everything from the first table, and only one column from the second table.  Right now I am specifing every single column I need, which is a drag.  Is there an easier way to grab everything from the first table and only the one column I want from the second table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

you need to specify the column name of the second table if it has the same columnName with the other table, you need to supply an `ALIAS` on it,

```
SELECT  tb1.*, tb2.x
FROM    tableA tb1
        INNER JOIN tableB tb2
            ON tb1.a = tb2.a
```