# Is there easier syntax for joining MySQL tables based on all columns?

Tags: mysql, join, syntax

I have two tables with many columns (~50).  Is there a way to join these tables using each column without explicitly naming each one in each table?

```
SELECT * from A
JOIN B
WHERE A.column1=B.column1
AND   A.column2=B.column2
AND   A.column3=B.column3
...
...
...
AND   A.column50=B.column50
```

There are many questions about various joins on stack ([e.g. this one on multiple column joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366780/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-multiple-columns)), but I was unable to find one that addressed this question.

[This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000572/better-way-to-select-all-columns-from-first-table-and-only-one-column-from-secon) gave me the idea for the following (which yields a syntax error in MySQL).

```
SELECT  tb1.*, tb2.x
FROM    tableA tb1
        INNER JOIN tableB tb2
            ON tb1.* = tb2.*
```

Is there something similarly brief to the above syntax that can be used to define this join without writing each column name twice?

*Why am I trying to doing this?*
In case this seems incredibly inefficient, the basis for this join is that there are rows in the first table that I'm planning on deleting provided I can get an exact match to them based on all the columns in the second.

The column names are the same in each table.

Comment: This won't work if columns are nullable. Keep in mind that `NULL = NULL` will return `NULL` and you don't get this row in resultset

Comment: @lad2025 good to know about the NULLage, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the column names are the same in both tables you can use a [Natural Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

```
SELECT a.* FROM a NATURAL JOIN b;
```

Here is an example using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de7e1/1/0)

Answer (score 4):

You can try `USING` when joining the tables. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
    A JOIN B
USING (column1,column2,column3, ... ,column50)
```

Note that the columns must have the same name in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

If there are not nullable columns then you can use this. Note that on phpMyAdmin shows an error but in MySQL console runs correct (it's a phpMyAdmin bug).

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) INTO @sql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'table_1' AND table_schema = 'your_database_table_schema ';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT table_1.* FROM table_1 JOIN table_2  USING (', @sql, ')');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've attempted this myself, I'll go out on a limb and say "no", there's no syntax allowing you to simplify this comparison.

However, and assuming you don't have NULLable columns (per lad2025), there is at least one workaround:

Because you're matching a large number of columns, you could merge both tables into a temporary table that has at least those columns in common.  If you create a `primary key` that includes all the columns for which you want to consider the rows identical, then your temporary table can only contain one of the rows.

So if you `INSERT` table A into the temporary table, then `INSERT IGNORE` table B into the temporary table, then the records of table B that DON'T appear in the temporary table are your matches.