# Select all fields from table A but single field from B?

Tags: abap, opensql

Is there a way in ABAP's OpenSQL to simplify the select columns in a `JOIN` when I want to grab all the fields of one table but only selected fields from the other table(s)?

For instance, in mysql [we can simply do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14000583/1103571):

```
SELECT  tb1.*, tb2.b, tb2.d
FROM       tableA tb1
INNER JOIN tableB tb2 ON tb1.x = tb2.a
```

However, OpenSQL does not seem to allow selecting `tb1~*, tb2~b, tb2~d` so I have to resort to this:

```
SELECT  tb1.x, tb1.y, tb1.z, tb2.b, tb2.d
FROM       tableA tb1
INNER JOIN tableB tb2 ON tb1.x = tb2.a
```

For very large tables, especially standard tables, this becomes unwieldy, difficult to read and more annoying to maintain.

**Is there a better way to select all fields of tb1 and some fields from tb2?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in the OpenSQL from 7.40 SP08. See this [article](http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/blog/2014/10/08/abap-news-for-740-sp08--open-sql).

The quotation from the article has that.

## Column Specification

> In the SELECT list, you can specify all columns of a data source using the syntax data_source~* from  7.40, SP08 on. This can be handy when working with joins.

```
SELECT scarr~carrname, spfli~*, scarr~url
       FROM scarr INNER JOIN spfli ON scarr~carrid = spfli~carrid
       INTO TABLE @DATA(result).
```

In the previous versions unfortunately one has to specify the columns one by one or use database native SQL for example with [ADBC](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abenadbc.htm).

Comment: Ha, I did think that I'd already used this before. Turns out this particular system is on 7.40 SP06.

Comment: Yep, know the pain. I am on the same system version 7.40 SP06. :)